# How to select an entire row based on multiple max date columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select the entire row, which has been filtered by 2 max date columns-

So if I have a table (Supply):

```
D_id |O_id  | O_date    | Start_date| amount 
400  |1     | 2018-2-7  | 2018-4-7  | 500
401  |1     | 2019-8-2  | 2019-10-1 | 1500
402  |1     | 2019-8-2  | 2019-12-7 | 200
403  |2     | 2016-4-10 | 2016-5-7  | 100
404  |2     | 2018-12-1 | 2018-12-17| 50
405  |2     | 2018-12-1 | 2019-1-1  | 2500
```

The output should hence group by the d_id and display that entire row which has the maximum O_date and the max start_date

```
D_id |O_id  | O_date    |  Start_date | amount |
402  |1     | 2019-8-2  | 2019-12-7   | 200
405  |2     | 2018-12-1 | 2019-1-1    | 2500
```

The problem I've been facing is just by using the max and group by condition, SQL mismatched the fields for each of the rows.

```
select max(O_DATE),
MAX(START_DATE),
D_ID,
AMOUNT,
O_ID
FROM SUPPLY
group by
O_ID;
```

Comment: Poor sample data. Add one O_id having different rows for the maximum O_date and the max start_date values. (And adjust the result accordingly.)

Comment: What if maximum O_date and the max start_date belongs to 2 separate row? And you must mean GROUP BY o_id instead of d_id - right?

Comment: Is it ever the case that the max o_date may not have the max start_date (and vice versa)

Comment: GROUP BY d_id will consider all 5 rows as 5 different GROUP.

Comment: Yes, the query should return the entire row which has the maximum o_date and also the max start_date, sometimes for each o_id the o_date will be the same in those cases we select the row which has the max start_date.

Comment: So the question is get the max start date within the max o_date

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thats what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

This following query should work for you. For your logic, START_DATE is common for both case and a joining between only START_DATE should do the tricks.

```
SELECT * FROM SUPPLY A
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT O_ID,
    MAX(O_DATE) O_DATE,
    MAX(START_DATE) START_DATE
    FROM SUPPLY
    group by O_ID
)B 
ON A.O_ID = B.O_ID
AND A.START_DATE = B.START_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
select
 t1.D_id, t1.O_id, t2.o_date, t2.Start_date, t1.amount 
from SUPPLY t1
outer apply (
     select O_id, Max(O_date) as o_date, MAX(Start_date) as Start_date from SUPPLY
        group by O_id
) as t2 where t2.O_id = t1.O_id and t2.o_date = t1.O_date and t2.Start_date = t1.Start_date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it it by joining your query to the table:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM SUPPLY s INNER JOIN (
  SELECT 
    max(O_DATE) O_DATE,
    max(START_DATE) START_DATE
  FROM SUPPLY
  GROUP BY O_ID
) g ON g.O_ID = s.O_ID AND g.O_DATE = s.O_DATE AND g.START_DATE = s.START_DATE
```

or with NOT EXISTS:

```
SELECT s.* 
FROM SUPPLY s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM SUPPLY
  WHERE O_ID = s.O_ID AND O_DATE > s.O_DATE AND START_DATE > s.START_DATE 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`O_DATE` takes a priority over `START_DATE`

```
select *
from SUPPLY t
join (
    select MAX(t.START_DATE) maxSd, m.maxOd, t.O_ID
    from SUPPLY t
    join (    
        select max(O_DATE) maxOd, O_ID
        from SUPPLY
        group by O_ID
    ) m on m.O_ID = t.O_ID and m.maxOd = t.O_DATE;
    group by m.maxOd, t.O_ID
) m2 on m2.O_ID = t.O_ID and m2.maxOd = t.O_DATE and m2.maxSd = t.START_DATE
```

Since 8 it can be simplyfied with WINDOW functions